# Ordering a Django QuerySet after slicing it

Tags: python, sql, django, orm

The [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated) say:

> ... even though slicing an unevaluated QuerySet returns another unevaluated QuerySet, modifying it further (e.g., adding more filters, or modifying ordering) is not allowed, since that does not translate well into SQL and it would not have a clear meaning either.

From this I take it to mean that doing something like this:

```
q1 = Pizza.objects.all()[0:5]
q2 = q1.order_by(...)
```

is not allowed. I have two question:

- why do the docs say this? I can understand that perhaps it doesn't translate into SQL well, but to me the "clear meaning" is that you get the first 5 pizza objects, then you order them by whatever criteria.
- what happens if you do this? I had been doing it for awhile, and the code was correct (but slow). Does it actually execute things in reverse -- order all the `Pizza` objects, then get the first 5?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you code the ORM, it's actually corresponding with SQL syntax. Especially, the ORM produces error SQL syntax. Of course It causes wrong.

This is your queryset:

```
q1 = Pizza.objects.all()[0:5]
q2 = q1.order_by(...)
```

The corresponding SQL syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM Pizza limit 5 order by your_column
```

So it's a obvious error.

How do code correct ORM? According to your requirement, I suggest this following to you:

```
q1 = Pizza.objects.all()[0:5]
q2 = q1.sorted(q1, key=lambda x: x.your_column)
```

It will return you expect.

---

I suggest you use `order by` before `slice` as the following:

```
q1 = Pizza.objects.all().order_by(...)[0:5]
```

Comment: Note that the point of this solution is that it does the ordering in Python. That's fine when it's only a few items, as here.

Comment: ^^ order_by() works by telling the database how to order the result set.. you are asking for the first 5 records.. but how do you know WHICH first 5 you will get if you have not specified the order?  You should order the set before you slice it so you know which records you are going to get.